# Change the icon size of MDRectangleFlatIconButton

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

How could I change the **size of the icon** inside my button? I tried it many ways, but neither of them worked. I will have 3 of theese buttons, but I want an icon for them as well. How could I change the size of the icon? Changing the border thickness would also be good.

My code:

```
MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
    text: "Hello"
    icon: "android"
    font_size: "100sp"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. You can check what does the button contains if you give it an id property (.kv file) `id: testButton` and then checking what is inside that button by performing (.py file) `self.ids['testButton'].ids` in your app container which for me is `class AppContainer(MDFloatLayout)`. The button contains an `'lbl_ic': <WeakProxy to <kivymd.uix.label.MDIcon object at 0x000001879DA4BF28>>` which attributes can be changed by  `self.ids['testButton'].ids["lbl_ic"].font_size = 200`.

**Any ideas how to do it in the .kv file?**

The running of my app:

```py
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return AppContainer()


MainApp().run()
```